# Display Image from excel in Python Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, jupyter-notebook

I’m trying to write a python code in jupyter that randomly picks AND Displays 5 images from an excel sheet column. All images have been uploaded from my local desktop into a single column. It's one image per cell.

This is how the excel (Pictures Column E) looks like: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2-FbQAXSv4M/maxresdefault.jpg

I have tried openpyxl and display.image options but nothing works.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This should be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994108/export-images-from-excel-using-python-with-specific-name

Comment: Using a popular package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039535/extract-images-from-excel-file-with-python#62045318

Comment: What is your question, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried openpyxl and display.image options but nothing works. In openpyxl I get the error that SheetImageLoader is not defined.